# What are the specifications for the internal iPad storage?

Tags: ipad

I can't seem to find any specifications for the internal storage for iPads. My initial interest has to do with read/write speed, life expectancy, endurance, degradation, etc.. like you'd see for SSD endurance ratings for example.

Is the life of the internal storage of the iPad NOT something app developers need to worry about?

Comment: Genuinely curious here.  Why is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: @Allan - For the same reason SSD manufacturers publish related specs? Or so that developers can be mindful of the impact of their apps? And if nothing else... why is the information so hard to find?! I work with a sizable team that uses iPads for work and a particular app we use has a log file that is insane, and disk impact experience makes me wonder if the volume of read/write by this app is degrading the storage in all of our iPads. It's definitely something I'd like to know. Unreasonable?

Comment: Considering [you’ll outlive the flash storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/289040/119271) of your device and that iOS is sandboxed unlike macOS and the API hooks are so tightly controlled, it would seem (to me at least) that the concerns a dev would have on a *normal” system are significantly mitigated on iOS.  But, I’m not a dev so I ask questions to learn.

Comment: Perhaps you can find the device used from a teardown - like this one (https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPad+Pro+11-Inch+Teardown/115457) which identifies the specific flash device - Toshiba TSB3247M61710TWNA1 flash storage (64 GB total) - and presumably somewhere you'll find it's specs - which is going to be an upper bound on what the performance could be ...

Comment: It's also possible that iPads with different storage sizes will have different storage configuration, as with the M-series Macs (and storm in a teacup over speeds).

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not publish such specifications for the internal storage of the iPad.

As such, it seems that it is Apple's policy that the precise specifications is not something app developers need to worry about.

As a developer, you will obviously in some specific cases have to be aware that you're working with flash based storage. However, it would be extremely rare to find an application developer working with something where it really matters for the programming whether the flash storage is actually based on chip X or chip Y with slightly different endurance levels.